# Java: Should occasionally used objects be included as a class member?

Tags: java, class, oop

I have a class `CodeText` as below:

```
public class CodeText{
    private char type;
    private int textCode;
    //Other members
}
```

Occasionally, if there is an error when a `Symbol` object refers to a `CodeText` object, I need to "record" that `Symbol` so that the `CodeText` "knows" who is referring it when error happens.

Currently I added another member "relatedSymbol" into class `CodeText` like below, but it feels like an ugly design.

```
public class CodeText{
    private char type;
    private int textCode;
    private Symbol relatedSymbol;
    //Other members
}
```

I'm not sure if the above can be improved. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: Sorry that I didn't provide enough background information.
My goal is as below:
For class `CodeText`, the `textCode` value is adjusted depending on the type.
E.g. if type is 'I'(meaning immediate), then `textCode` is unchanged;
if type is 'E'(meaning external), then `textCode` should be recomputed and then refer to the address of an external `Symbol`.

But occasionally, the value of `textCode` might be wrong. For example, if type is "E" but the value of `textCode` points
to an illegal `Symbol`, then this error should be recorded and `CodeText` object should "know" which `Symbol` it tries to refer.

Comment: Hard to say without really seeing the purpose of those classes and the overall architecture. But generally it's not a problem by and of itself to have a member that is most often a null

Comment: I'd start by giving proper names to attributes and classes. Having a class called `CodeText` that has an attribute `textCode` seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally, if there is an error when a Symbol object refers to a
>   CodeText object, I need to "record" that Symbol so that the CodeText
>   "knows" who is referring it when error happens.

If your objective is to record/trace  the errors, it is NOT a good idea to mix the error causing `Symbol` into the existing `CodeText` class which will break the single responsibility principle (look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), so you might need one more class like `ErrorRecorder` as shown below, whose sole responsibility is to record the errors.

```
public class ErrorRecorder {

    private final CodeText codeText;

    private final Symbol relatedSymbol;

    private final LocalDateTime errorCreatedDateTime;

    public ErrorRecorder(CodeText codeText, Symbol relatedSymbol,
                     LocalDateTime errorCreatedDateTime) {
        super();
        //Add some validations to the fields
        this.codeText = codeText;
        this.relatedSymbol = relatedSymbol;
        this.errorCreatedDateTime = errorCreatedDateTime;
    }

    //Add getters
}
```

Comment: "Yes, you can't mix errors into the existing CodeText class" -- given how vague OP's code description is, that's a very strong assumption

Comment: OP's point is to record the errors, you can go through the question again

Comment: I'm not sure if this really enhances the model or makes it more complex than it should be. Without more info from OP, I can only say this is opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them separated, you could maybe have an other object which records such errors

```
public class ReferenceError {
    private CodeText codeText;
    private Symbol symbol;
    //Other members
}
```

or simply use a `Pair<CodeText, Symbol>` if you really don't need to record anything else

Then you can keep them in a list
`List<ReferenceError>` or `List<Pair<CodeText, Symbol>>`

Or even a `Map<CodeText, Symbol[]>` if you need to record several errors for a same CodeText